# Inserting Error In MS Access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

What is my error here?

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AccountMaintenance(FirstName, LastName, " + 
        "Username, Password) values('" + txt_FirstName.Text + "','" + txt_LastName.Text + 
        "','" + txt_Username.Text + "','" + txt_Password.Text + "')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Data has Successfully Save!");

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error due to: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." that my Error.

Comment: Maybe Password is a reserved word? it is in Jet 4.0 [List of reserved words in Jet 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) . Escape it using square brackets like `[Password]`

Comment: I don get it. "reserved word"?

Comment: There are some words which you are not supposed to use to name your table,fields etc. If you have to use them, you will have to **escape** them , for Access and SQL Server you use the square brackets to escape `[wordhere]`.